# Bounded Maximal Solutions of ODE System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $(x(t), y(t))$ be a maximal solution of the following diferential equation:

$(x,y)' = (-x + y, \hspace{0.2cm} log(10+|x|) - y)$

and consider $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ a point in its domain. Show that both real functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are limited for $t \geq t_0$.

*Attempts*: I've tried to write $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in a way that makes it possible to apply Gronwall's Lemma for each one of them, but the inequalities don't work quite right. Trying to solve this ode system without using exponencial of matrices (which we can't use) seems difficult enough.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Let $u(t) = x^2(t) + y^2(t)$. Prove that $\log(10|+|x|) \le |x|$ for $x \ge 3$ and use this to prove that $u'(t) \le 0$ if $u(t)$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks a lot!! It worked. Care to explain why you defined $u(t)$ as $x^2(t) + y^2(t)$?

Comment: That's the first guess for an ODE system that has a (sub)linear right hand side.